How does the addition of OP_CAT improve Lightning?
In a debate about OP_CAT, it was claimed without further evidence that the addition of the OP_CAT opcode would "improve Lightning". Could you expound how OP_CAT would improve lightning?

OP_CAT on its own has limited applicability to the lightning routed payment network itself - it cannot be used to build Lightning Symmetry channels. It could be used to potentially reduce the number of transactions needed in resolving lightning penalty without incurring additional round-trips, but the cost of the CAT script and required witness data would likely exceed the savings in transaction inputs and outputs.
However, OP_CAT covenants can be used to enable building improved end user experiences linked to the lightning network, such as timeout trees, Ark, and potentially channel factories.

So to be clear, you are not aware of a way to use OP_CAT to clearly improve lightning today?
